# Understanding arguments in Haskell type classes and instances

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand a Haskell class declaration and instance from a [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=1EA31D76684217BC728F916144BC6C38?doi=10.1.1.109.6853&rep=rep1&type=pdf). I am trying to understand the class declaration:

```
class (Surfaces v o, Paths a b (v o)) => Vehicles v o a b
```

My current understanding is that the first occurance of types "v o" in the `Vehicles` context seems to refer to two distinct data types. I assume that it is the same for the "v o" on the right of `=>`.

Question 1

Is my understanding correct?  Does the bracketed "(v o)" in the `Vehicles` context refer a type constructor and its argument, rather than two independent types?

Question 2:

Is the instance OK? Why do I need `FlexibleInstances`

```
 instance Vehicles Boat Person Route (Water Source)
```

I apologize for the level of detail, but I believe that the context is important to my question.
Regards,
Pat

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
data Person = Person deriving Show
data House a = House a  deriving Show
data Boat a  = Boat a deriving Show
data Route a b = Route a b deriving Show
data Source = Source deriving Show
data Destination = Destination deriving Show
data Water a = Water a deriving Show
data Land = Land deriving Show

-- The three top level classes are constructor classes, indicated by the signatures of the methods (not the class header).
-- The kinds in the class headers have kinds * and *->*
-- "Containers a b" stands for all container types "a" holding things of type "b".
class Containers a b where
 insert :: b -> a b -> a b
 remove :: b -> a b -> a b
 whatsIn :: a b -> [b]

-- Type "a" is the type of  surface
-- Type "b" is the type object on the surface e.g. boat is on water.
class Surfaces a b where
 put :: b -> a b -> a b
 takeOff :: b -> a b -> a b
 whatsOn :: a b -> [b]


-- The path class represents motion
-- Type "c" represents the moving object e.g Boat.
-- Type "a" route
-- Type "b" origin and destination place
class Paths a b c where
 move :: c -> a b c -> a b c
 origin, destination :: a b c -> b
 whereIs :: a b c -> c -> b

class People p
class HeavyLoads l
class Surfaces w o => WaterBodies w o
class Containers h o => Houses h o

-- The types "v o" in the Vehicles the context seems to refer to two distinct data types.
-- I assume that it is the same for the "v o" on the right of =>
-- But "(v o)" in the Vehicles the context seems to refer a type constructor and its argument??.
-- Vehicles are derived from surfaces (affording to ride on the vehicle) and paths (affording motion). 
-- Vehicles type class has  parameters for
--  the type "o" of the transported object
--  the type "a" of the path,
--  the type "b" of the origin and destination places.
--  "o" has kind *, "a" has kind *->*->*,  "v" has kind *->*
class (Surfaces v o, Paths a b (v o)) => Vehicles v o a b

instance Surfaces Boat Person
instance WaterBodies Boat Person  -- Boats carrying people on water
instance Paths Route (Water Source) (Boat Person) -- boat moving on water carrying people
instance Vehicles Boat Person Route (Water Source)  -- Boat as a vehicle
```

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1
>
> Does the bracketed "(v o)" in the Vehicles context refer a type constructor and its argument, rather than two independent types?

In the constraint `Surfaces v o`, `v` and `o` are two separate type arguments to class `Surfaces`. Constraint `Paths a b (v o)` has three arguments: `a`, `b`, `(v o)`. The third is `v` applied to `o`, so we can infer parameter `v` to class `Vehicles` is a type constructor, kind `* -> *`.

I'm not sure what you're trying to say by "independent types": `v`, `o`, are distinct parameters to `Vehicles`. The constraints are telling us we can't freely choose just any types for `a`, `b`, `v`, `o`, so they're all inter-dependent.

> Question 2:
>
> Is the instance OK? Why do I need `FlexibleInstances`
>
> ```
>    instance Vehicles Boat Person Route (Water Source)
> ```

Firstly, class `Vehicles` needs `FlexibleContexts`. That's because not all of the constraints are of the form class name followed by bare type variables. Argument `(v o)` is the culprit.

Similarly for that instance, not all the type arguments are plain type constructors or constructors followed by bare type vars. Argument `(Water Source)` is the culprit. If it were `(Water b)`, that wouldn't need `FlexibleInstances`.